# What to do with a downward band in the Residuals vs Fitted plot from linear regressions?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, residuals, diagnostic

I got a residuals vs fitted plot with a clear downward pattern from a linear regression model and am wondering what are some of the sensible things to do in this situation? [image]

Doing a boxcox transformation does not help much in correcting the pattern (bc=0.3 from boxcox()). A log transformation (with an offset ) of the responses does not help either. [image]

My response variable is vehicle miles traveled, so it is truncated at 0. I am aware that a truncated model such as tobit models likely works better for my data, but the downward pattern persists in the residuals vs fitted plot from the tobit model, so I am hoping to address the issue with the simplest model possible.

In term of independent variables, HHC_MSA is a categorical variable labeling different regions in the US, while HHSIZE is the number of persons in a household. I tried non-linear transformation of the HHSIZE variable with splines::ns, the downward pattern tilts up somewhat, but persists [image].

Any suggestions and comments are appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Following @Glen_b 's suggestion, I added a residuals vs fitted plot from a hurdle model, however, the downward band persists there, similarly for a zero-inflated negative binomal model and a tobit model.

[image: residuals vs fitted plot from hurdle model <code>mfit3 <- hurdle(as.integer(VMT_MILE)~HHC_MSA+HHSIZE, data=act2)</code>]

Below are the code and data that replicate my results (please be aware of large data files - csv files more than 400MB):

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(AER)
library(MASS)

#Down data from [ORNL](http://nhts.ornl.gov/download.shtml#2009) and unzip
zip_url <- "http://nhts.ornl.gov/2009/download/Ascii.zip"
data_dir <- "data/"
data_file <- file.path(data_dir, "Ascii/DAYV2PUB.CSV")
zip_file <- file.path(data_dir, "NHTS2009.zip")

if (!dir.exists(data_dir)) dir.create(data_dir)

if (!file.exists(data_file)) {
  download.file(zip_url, destfile=zip_file, method="libcurl")
  unzip(zip_file, exdir = data_dir)
}
stopifnot(file.exists(data_file))

act <- read_csv(file.path(data_dir, "Ascii/DAYV2PUB.CSV"))
act2 <- act %>% 
  mutate(VMT_MILE=ifelse(VMT_MILE < 0, 0, VMT_MILE),
         HHC_MSA=ifelse(HHC_MSA %in% c("XXXX", "-1", "-9"), NA, HHC_MSA)) %>% 
  group_by(HOUSEID) %>% 
  summarize(VMT_MILE=sum(VMT_MILE, na.rm=0),
            HHSIZE=first(HHSIZE),
            HHVEHCNT=first(HHVEHCNT),
            HHC_MSA=first(HHC_MSA)) %>% 
  filter(HHVEHCNT<=12, VMT_MILE<=200)

summary(mfit0 <- lm(VMT_MILE~HHC_MSA+HHSIZE, data=act2))
plot(mfit0, which=1)

summary(mfit0_ns <- lm(VMT_MILE~HHC_MSA+ns(HHSIZE, 3), data=act2))
plot(mfit0_ns, which=1)

# adds 0.1 to VMT_MILE as boxcox requires positive responses
bct <- boxcox(mfit1 <- lm(VMT_MILE+0.1~HHC_MSA+HHSIZE, data=act2), plotit=F)
(bc <- bct$x[which.max(bct$y)])
summary(mfit1 <- lm(((VMT_MILE+0.1)^bc + 1)/bc~HHC_MSA+HHSIZE, data=act2))
plot(mfit1, which=1)

summary(mfit2 <- lm(log(VMT_MILE+0.1)~HHC_MSA+HHSIZE, data=act2))
plot(mfit2, which=1)

library(pscl)
summary(mfit3 <- hurdle(as.integer(VMT_MILE)~HHC_MSA+HHSIZE, data=act2))
residuals_ <- resid(mfit3, type="response")
fitted_ <- fitted(mfit3, type="response")
plot(fitted_, residuals_)
```

Comment: Note that the "top" of the band of residuals is parallel to the line at the bottom. The line at the bottom is cause by the "0" values. Is there a hard maximum on the response ("vehicle miles travelled") in your data set?

Comment: max(act$VMT_MILE)=3600, but I excluded observations whose VMT_MILE  > 200 (99.9 percentile), as lm diagnostic plots identify higher values as potential outliers.

Comment: That choice (with the 0's) accounts for the down-sloping band in your residuals. Rather than use an obviously inappropriate distributional model, one actually suitable for the kind of measurement you have (where responses are necessarily non-negative but with exact zeros possible) might be better. A zero-inflated gamma GLM / gamma hurdle model would seem to be an obvious thing to consider.  An alternative if you really want a linear regression would be to build a logistic regression model for the "0" vs ">0" part and then for the ">0" observations, model log-miles against your predictors...

Comment: ... That might avoid the need to remove data (with consequent issues that may bring)

Comment: @Glen_b, thanks and I appreciate your suggestion. I did try hurdle and zero-inflated negative binomial models in the pscl package (after converting my responses to integer), as well as an AER::tobit model, but the downward band persists. I updated my question with a residuals vs fitted plot from the hurdle model. Any additional suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: The broad appearance of the residual plot probably won't substantively change, especially at the 0 end (well it might curve rather than be straight) -- that there's a band is perhaps unavoidable; but for some models it's actually what you should see. The point is that plot tells you that the ordinary linear regression model won't be right, and why.

Comment: @Glen_b, I understand the zeros need to be addressed with more sophisticated models. My concern here is whether the persistent downward band is an indication of (other) bad model assumption (no matter lm, boxcox, hurdle/tobit, or two-step models) and whether/how it should be addressed. My final model specifications have more independent variables, but the downward band is there too. Thanks!